# Spark Model to use in Java Application

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

For analysis.
I know we can use the Save function and load the Model in Spark application. But it works only in Spark application (Java, Scala, Python).

We can also use the PMML and export the model to other type of application.

Is there any way to use a Spark model in a Java application?

Answer (score 2):

I am one of the creators of MLeap. Check us out, it is meant for exactly your use case. If there is a transformer you need that is not currently supported, get in touch with me and we will get it in there.

Our serialization format is solely JSON/Protobuf right now, so it is very portable and supports large models like RandomForest. You can serialize your model to a zip file then load it up wherever.

Take a look at our demo to get a use case:
https://github.com/TrueCar/mleap-demo

Comment: It was linked in another comment, but here is the github page again: https://github.com/TrueCar/mleap

Comment: What models are supported? Is this compatible with Spark 2.* ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently no, your options are to use PMML for those models that support it, or write your own framework for using models outside of Spark.

There is movement towards enabling this (see [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13944)). You could also check out [Mleap](https://github.com/truecar/mleap).