# Loading Mllib models outside Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I'm training a model in spark with mllib and saving it:

```
val model = SVMWithSGD.train(training, numIterations)

model.save(sc, "~/model")
```

but I'm having trouble loading it from a java app without spark to make real time predictions.

```
SparkConf sconf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Application").setMaster("local");
SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(sconf);
SVMModel model = SVMModel.load(sc, "/model");
```

I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkConf
    at ModelUser$.main(ModelUser.scala:11)
    at ModelUser.main(ModelUser.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.SparkConf
```

Is there a way to load the model in normal java app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Model to use in Java Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041051/spark-model-to-use-in-java-application)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look PMML model export [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-pmml-model-export.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, currently only few models have this export to PMML method. :(

Answer (score 0):

PPML model export in spark is not being maintained anymore, and only the old RDD api support it. 
I've been using [jpmml-sparkml](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sparkml) to solve the problem. It also has the java runtime for standalone model execution.